# Light will not shut off when dimmer "switch" is tapped

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling, led

I have a 40W equivalent LED dimmable bulb in my ceiling fixture.  The  dimmer switch will control it, but it never shuts off out when I tap the switch to turn it off.

Comment: If it is full brightness when you tap the switch, does it stay full brightness or does it go dim-but-not-off? What model is the dimmer switch?

Comment: Is the dimmer designed for LED dimming and does it have a neutral wire?  It sounds like they're using "That 70s tech" of powering the dimmer by  leaking current through the light bulbs... which will indeed make LEDs glow.

Comment: What make and model are the bulb and dimmer in qustion?

Comment: Sounds like a faulty or worn out switch. Get it replaced.